# Problema ao fazer requisição AJAX DELETE enviando JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-request

Ao fazer uma requisição `DELETE` numa url que não suporta `OPTIONS` o navegador me retorna:

> 405 Method Not Allowed

Existe alguma forma de impedir, no meu código JavaScript, que o navegador envie um pré-request `OPTIONS` antes de enviar um `DELETE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não (*). Quando o navegador está enviando requisições AJAX para um serviço, ele vai mandar todos os cookies relacionados ao domínio do serviço. Para proteger o cenário onde você navega para `http://site.malvado.com/`, e o site manda um DELETE (ou POST, ou PUT) para `http://seu.banco.com/contas`, se o site usa um mecanismo de autenticação simples baseado na presença de um cookie do usuário, então o site irá apagar as suas contas. Para prevenir esse tipo de ataque, quando um navegador (moderno) está enviando requisições para um domínio que não seja o da página, ele segue o [protocolo CORS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), que requer uma requisição OPTIONS. Se o servidor está ciente da possibilidade desses ataques (ou seja, não usa uma forma de autenticação que seja vulnerável), então ele irá *habilitar o CORS* e saberá responder às requisições OPTIONS. Se o serviço não aceita o OPTIONS, então é possível que ele não esteja preparado para lidar com os ataques de *cross-domain*.

(*) No entanto, há situações em que você quer passar por cima dessa restrição. Algumas opções:

- utilização de um proxy *no mesmo domínio da sua página*: a sua página faz a requisição para um serviço na aplicação. Como o domínio é o mesmo da página, a restrição de CORS não existe. O navegador irá enviar os cookies *do seu domínio*, e o seu código no servidor (e.g., PHP, C#) pode fazer a requisição ao serviço final. Note que você não terá nenhum dos cookies daquele domínio, o que "salva" o serviço do ataque
- uso de algum plug-in no navegador: dependendo da implementação do plug-in ele pode ter acesso a todos os cookies, e na sua implementação, ele não tem restrição de CORS. Mas essa solução requer que o usuário instale o plug-in na sua máquina, o que limita bastante a sua utilização.

Comment: Realmente ele não aceita OPTIONS. O interessante é que isso não acontece quando faço POST. Você poderia me indicar uma extensão(Chrome)?

Comment: Sinto, não conheço nenhuma extensão. Se o servidor suporta o POST, então pode ser que seja uma versão que só esteja configurado para suportar GET e POST. Se for esse o caso, e o servidor suporte o [X-HTTP-Method-Override](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx), você pode tentar usá-lo para ver se funciona.